# When are list-questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic-off-topic, question-closure, list-question

Perhaps this is a bit too broad a question, but we'll see. Here goes.

---

Right now, the consensus seems to be that list-question SWRs are opinion-based or too broad (and thus off-topic). List-question SWRs are ones that, rather than looking for words that fit some sort of *semantic* criteria, look for words that fit certain *derivational/orthographical* criteria.

(The most-maligned SWR list questions are [these](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/595565/unusual-words-used-to-denote-a-specific-length-of-time) types, which are- though interesting-  rightly closed.)

My issue is that many of these are closed inconsistently- we close some of them and we leave some of them open. Looking just at the titles of the following questions, there's no way to predict which ones are open and which ones have been closed. They're quite similar, and their status seems to rest more on who was going through the review-queues at the time in question.

In each of them, any answer is as valid as the next, as long as it's not factually incorrect. It's essentially going to turn into a list of data-point-answers.

Open:

- [Is there any word in English where "th" sounds like "t+h"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310780)
- [Is there any English word starting with "gh" and "gh" is not pronounced as /ɡ/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244514)
- [Does the letter C by itself make the sound /kə/ in any word besides Cthulhu?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/601751)
- [Are there any words in English pronounced with /eː/ which aren't spelt with a following "r"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169430)
- [Are there any words in English pronounced with /e/ at the end?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169429)
- [Are there any words in English that have a plural with a separate derivation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74227)
- [Are there any words pronounced with an unstressed short monophthong at the end of word that are not /ə/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173728)
- [Is "princessship" a real word? Are there any other words which have the same letter 3 times consecutively?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15786)

Closed:

- [Are there any English words starting with an "ny" sound?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331011)
- [Are there any English words pronounced with sounds/syllables that aren't part of the spelling?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505788)
- [Word with three consecutive L's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38521)
- [Do any words have three or more correct spellings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180658)

There's one more genre of list-question that I can think of- they aren't looking for a word, but again, any accurate answer is as defensible as another; there's really no way to separate them fairly:

- [Do 'ration' and 'station' rhyme in any English accents?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/603845)
- [Usage of "the cubalow" - Has anyone heard the phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320088)
- [Is pronouncing "wash" as "wish" a known feature of any accent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/434021)

(Some of these ones are de-list-ifiable through)

So what is it? Are such questions on or off-topic? Should such questions be left open or closed?

([Related](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15441/not-all-list-questions-are-off-topic))

Comment: The activities of CV and VTR are to some extent a matter of personal judgment. There are users who are quite strict in applying the rules, others tend to save questions and answers for the amount of useful information they provide. Among the 128K+ questions you’ll find many other “inconsistencies” in that respect. –

Comment: The problem with list requests that is most striking is: I am doing a research paper and want you not to help me, but to do all the work. After all, I set up the assignment, you have to do *something*.